# debian 8 & python 2.7 install matplotlib failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to install matlibplot 1.5.0 for python 2.7 on Debian 8. I have installed libfreetype6-dev && libpng-dev, but it still raise error:

```
    freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                   could not be found.  You may need to install the
                   development package.]

    ============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: I have solve the problem after change the setup.py. I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like development package is missing. Solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Comment: Yes. I have solve the problem after change the setup.py. I think it's a bug.